# parsing/reading öäü from xml file

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing, libgdx

I created a StringManager for different languages and like to read characters like öäü from the xml but this fails. I get some "fanzy characters" so not the right ones.

here i do parse the xml

```
public StringManager()
{
    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal(MainClass.config.getValueOf(
            String.class, FILE));
    try
    {
        // parse the xml. Its an hashtable than!
        this.xml = this
                .parse(Base64Coder.decodeString(handle.readString()));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

i know that the decoding doesnt do something to that. Tried decoded too.

This is how i get a String:

```
public String getString(String stringname)
{
    try
    {
        return this.xml.get(stringname);
        // catch if not found
    }
    catch (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException e)
    {
        Logger.error("String not found: " + stringname + " "
                + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```

and here is a small sett from the xml

```
<root>
<!-- German -->
<de_DE>
....

    <level_text>level</level_text>
    <skill_name>Skill Name</skill_name>
    <back_to_skillmenu>Zurück zum Skillmenu</back_to_skillmenu> <!-- here it does not return the right value -->
    <back_to_game>Zurück zum Spiel</back_to_game> <!-- here it does not return the right value -->
</de_DE>
</root>
```

Comment: How does it fail? I don't see any encoding declaration in your `StringManager`. When dealing with text you always should define an encoding/character-set.

Comment: the XMLReader does parse the whole xml so i do not encode it myself. It doent return an öäü it does return some characters that cant be displayed with the font so i get some kind of squares for example. The font does have öäü i just checked it. Link to the reader: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by encoding the String with utf-8 myself. Thanks to @A4L for the hint!

```
public String getString(String stringname)
{
    try
    {
        byte ptext[] = this.xml.get(stringname).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
        return value;
        // catch if not found
    }
    catch (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException e)
    {
        Logger.error("String not found: " + stringname + " "
                + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Logger.error("encoding failed " + stringname + " "
                + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```